# How do I change the color of geom_line when I have multiple lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot some data and so far I got not problem using ggplot2... the code I've used so far is as follows:

```
ggplot(aes(x=mo,y=Sulphate, color=yr, group=yr),data=dd.tot)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=mo, ymin=Sulphate-Sulphate.1, ymax=Sulphate+Sulphate.1), width=0.25)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle("Sodium 0-1 um")+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Sodium ng m3")
ggsave("Sodium.png", plot=last_plot(), device=png(), path="C:/Users/Raffaello/Desktop/R_Rita/Dekati_tot", width = 20, height = 14, units = c("cm"))
```

which gives me the results I want
[image: ggplot graph]

Now, since I need to add multiple lines, I changed the code and added two strings of geom_line

```
ggplot(aes(x=Date), data=dati)+
 geom_line(aes(y=Sodium, linetype="PM10"))+
 geom_line(aes(y=Sodium_ng_tot, linetype="Dekati Sum", color=yr))+
 ggtitle("Sodium")+
 xlab("Date")+
 ylab("Sodium ng m3")
```

But instead of the different color "blocks" for the different years, I got a gradient from black to light blue

[image: ggplot graph]

Is there a way to get the same colors as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot` uses gradient color scales for continuous data and qualitiative color scales for categorical data.

Your `dati$yr` column must be numeric (continuous), and your `dd.tot$yr` column is `factor` (categorical). Convert with `dati$yr = factor(dati$yr)`, or change the mapping to `color = factor(yr)` inside your `aes()`.